# Calculating the reduced mass of N particles

Tags: python, implementation

I am trying to implement the following in Python: I have an array of masses, say, 3. I want to calculate the reduced mass the following way: I take the first element of the array as m1 and the second element as m2. Then I will compute the reduced mass of these two. Then I take the third element of the array, m3, and calculate the reduced mass of m1 and m3.
Next, I'll do the same with the second element m2, which is then my reference particle. I take the reduced mass of m2 and m1 and m2 and m3 and so on. Can anyone help me with implementing this? I have quite the difficulties in understanding the logics behind this.

```
     def reduced_mass(self,masses):
        """
        Calculate the the reduced mass of two particles each. 
        Parameters
        ----------
        masses : array
            GIVE MASSES AS AN ARRAY.

        Returns
        -------
        reduced_masses : array
            REDUCED MASSES OF A REFERENCE PARTICLE AND REDUCED MASS WITH ALL THE OTHER PARTICLES.
        """
        num_particles = len(masses)
        reduced_masses = np.empty((num_particles - 1) * num_particles // 2)
        index = 0
        for i in range(num_particles):
            for j in range(i + 1, num_particles):
                reduced_masses[index] = (masses[i] * masses[j]) / (masses[i] + masses[j])
                index += 1
        return reduced_masses
```

I am expecting an array of reduced masses. If I have three masses, then I expect the array to have len(array)=6 (i.e. 3 reference particle, each interact with the other two). However, the array does not have the correct length and the correct numbers (but I do not get an overall error in Python).

Comment: So for 3 elements, you want the final result to be an array of length 6? Wouldn't you want to append to the array then?

Comment: Hi B, thanks a lot for the comment! What do you mean by appending?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal the approach in the code is to pre-allocate a numpy array of the correct length up front - which is one way to do it

Comment: @slothrop I see now. The issue seems to be `index` starting at 0 as opposed to the length of the original array of elements.

Comment: *"I expect the array to have len(array)=6 (i.e. 3 reference particle, each interact with the other two)"* If you want two entries for each pair of particles - i.e. to treat (x, y) and (y, x) as separate interactions, then you'd want to (a) remove the `// 2` in the array size, (b) start your `for j` loop at 0, not at i+1, (c) avoid calculating the interaction of each particle with itself.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot guys. Yeah, I originally thought about doing it with lists, however, arrays seem to be more efficient when dealing with larger numbers/elements? And I want to do it with N particles eventually.

Comment: Right, there's nothing wrong with using an array. Your question is more about how to represent pairwise interactions. If you consider (x, y) and (y, x) to be different interactions that should be separately represented, then 3 particles give 6 pairs (`(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)`). If you consider (x, y) and (y, x) to be the same thing that should be represented only once, then 3 particles give 3 pairs (`(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)`). It sounds like you want the first version of this, but your current code implements the second version.

Comment: If you want to use a numpy array, consider using a 2-dimensional array. Then you can get a nice natural representation where `arr[i, j]` represents the interaction between the i-th and j-th particles.

Comment: Wow, yes that is so right haha! It's the first version I want. But what is not correctly implemented? I guess I should change the initial array "reduced_masses"?

Comment: @Charlotte I put the solution in the answer to the original post. you have to go through all possible pairs in the double loop, except the case i=j.

Comment: So you'd need to change the size of the array (just remove the `// 2`), and in the loop, start the `for j` loop from 0. @geofisue 's answer shows how the loops can be constructed to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much @slothrop and geofisue for helping me out and taking the time (and also BRemmelzwaal) ! I just implemented it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it using a list in which you append the masses.

```py
import numpy as np

def reduced_mass(masses):
    """
    Calculate the the reduced mass of two particles each. 
    Parameters
    ----------
    masses : array
    GIVE MASSES AS AN ARRAY.

    Returns
    -------
    reduced_masses : array
    REDUCED MASSES OF A REFERENCE PARTICLE AND REDUCED MASS WITH ALL THE OTHER PARTICLES.
    """
    num_particles = len(masses)
    reduced_masses = []
    for i in range(num_particles):
        for j in range(num_particles):
            if j != i:
                print(i,j)
                redmass = (masses[i] * masses[j]) / (masses[i] + masses[j])
                reduced_masses.append(redmass)
    return reduced_masses

masas = [1,2,3]
reds1 = reduced_mass(masas)
```

Comment: In the double loop you go through all possible pairs except the case i=j.